# Why is my ternary operator code returning both conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, tags, ternary-operator

In my Rails app, which form field I type in when creating a new product dictates which image shows up. If I enter in the 'verdict' text box, that means the product sucks so I show a greyed out, inactive Amazon button.

If I type in the 'goodverdict' box, it's a legit product so we see Amazon's buy button and it's linked to the product, because I enter the URL into the form. I first tried with `present?` and just recently switched it to `presence` (which is what's below). Same result with both.

But when I only type in the 'goodverdict' box, I get BOTH buttons (ie as if both arguments were true) and text saying "false?" appears.

[image]

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="belowvid">
<%= @product.verdict.presence %> ? <%=@product.verdict %> <br> <%= image_tag('https://s3.amazonaws.com/isitcrap/amazon+gray+button.jpg', width: 275) %> :
<%= @product.goodverdict %> <br>
<%= link_to image_tag("https://s3.amazonaws.com/isitcrap/amazon-Button.png", width: 275), @product.buylink.html_safe, target: :_blank %>
```

This is from a partial which is being rendered by another partial rendered by the index.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages. Don't use images to demonstrate code or error conditions. Instead copy and paste the information into the question, formatting it appropriately. Links to images rot then break and then the question will be missing essential information. Also, images can't be indexed by the search engines making it more difficult for others to find your question and supplied answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ternary operator isn't running because it isn't in the ruby section, but in the html.

Only stuff inside of `<%`/`%>` tags gets run as ruby... everything else gets printed to the screen just as html.

in this case - what you probably want is something like this:

```
<% if @product.verdict.present? %>
  <%= @product.verdict %> <br> <%= image_tag('https://s3.amazonaws.com/isitcrap/amazon+gray+button.jpg', width: 275) %>
<% else %>
 <%= @product.goodverdict %> <br>
 <%= link_to image_tag("https://s3.amazonaws.com/isitcrap/amazon-Button.png", width: 275), @product.buylink.html_safe, target: :_blank %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks!! I feel dumb at how simple this was, but also glad since it didn't take a lot of your time. However... :)

Comment: I was wrong about thinking I ID'd this problem so re-posting this comment:
crap, hit enter too soon. I was going to say, since using that code, now the 'buylist' attribute (which is the link to the product that I paste into the 'buylink' field in the form, and that makes the buy button link to the product) is giving me a routing error, saying: No route matches [GET] "/products/www.espn.com", which doesn't make sense. The @products.buylink.html_safe was unchanged.

Comment: OH... MY... GOD... it's because when I was entering www.espn.com real fast during test entries, I wasn't including http://, and the amazon links always did, that's why they always worked. wow...

Comment: hehe... my personal opinion is that silly errors/bugs are the best - because they're so easy to solve! :)